# Unable to Stream Responses from AWS Lambda using @vendia/serverless-express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

I am facing difficulties in streaming responses from AWS Lambda. Initially, I attempted to use the serverless-http package for this purpose, but I learned that it doesn't support streaming. Subsequently, I switched to the @vendia/serverless-express package, hoping it would resolve the issue. However, even with this package, I can still not achieve streaming functionality.

My code:

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http"),
  express = require("express"),
  morgan = require("morgan"),
  helmet = require("helmet"),
  bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
  awsServerlessExpress = require("@vendia/serverless-express");

const cors = require("cors");

const rootPrefix = ".",
  coreConstants = require(rootPrefix + "/config/coreConstants"),
  apiRoutes = require(rootPrefix + "/routes/index"),
  setResponseHeader = require(rootPrefix + "/middlewares/setResponseHeader");

// Set worker process title.
process.title = "";

const app = express();

// Use Morgan middleware to log requests
app.use(morgan("combined"));

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// Helmet can help protect the app from some well-known web vulnerabilities by setting HTTP headers appropriately.
app.use(helmet());

// Node.js body parsing middleware. Default limit is 100kb
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "2mb" }));

// Parsing the URL-encoded data with the qs library (extended: true). Default limit is 100kb
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "2mb" }));

app.get("/stream", async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    res.write(`Line ${i}\n`);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
  res.end();
});

// Set response header to prevent response caching
app.use(setResponseHeader());

// If running in development mode, start the server on port 8080, else export handler for lambda
if (
  coreConstants.ENVIRONMENT === "development" ||
  coreConstants.ENVIRONMENT === "test"
) {
  console.log("Server running on 8080");
  app.listen(8080);
  module.exports = { handler: app };
} else {
  // Export the handler for Lambda on production
  module.exports.handler = awsServerlessExpress({ app })
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only AWS Lambda framework that currently supports streamify responses is Middy.

```js
import middy from '@middy/core'
import { createReadableStream } from '@datastream/core'

export const handler = middy({ streamifyResponse: true }).handler(
  (event, context) => {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
      },
      body: createReadableStream('...') // or string
    }
  }
)
```

https://middy.js.org/docs/intro/streamify-response